# Reference request for effect of change of coordinates on points and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I've seen brief mentions of a distinction between the **points** of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and **vectors** in that plane, and how they transform differently under change of coordinates. I'd appreciate a reference that explains more about this subject, hopefully more formally. Below is an excerpt from Artin "Algebra", that mentions this difference.

[image: Artin Algebra]

Comment: With translations they're called affine transformations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

Comment: @CyclotomicField I've read Wikipedia, but it's hard to learn from. do you mean that vectors are affine transformations?

Comment: Translations are affine meaning that adding a vector is affine. Given a linear transformation $\phi$ then an affine transformation $\varphi$ can be given in the form $\varphi(x) = \phi(x) + b$ for some fixed vector $b$.